# Automatically clear downloaded items in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

It bothers me that when I download something in Google Chrome it appears on the bar on the bottom of the screen until I close it or clear "downloaded" list. I used to have extension installed that automatically cleared "downloaded" list every few seconds, but it seems like this extension got removed from store and is no longer visible in my Google Chrome. At the time of writing this the latest and installed on my PC version of Google Chrome is 71. Said extension worked when I had Google Chrome version 6x, I don't remember exactly, but it was sixty something.

Is there any way to do that with Google Chrome 71? Something like a tweak of advanced settings? I am looking for Linux solution mainly, but I guess that if there is a solution it would be for Google Chrome on all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension looks like the one you might be looking for:

[Clear Downloads - Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-downloads/bknoejjhcfmakcibhifepfkegpjdnadk?hl=en)

Bear in mind it will also clear your downloads list (as well as the bar along the bottom).

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted it to clear my downloads list too :)